# Isekai manga where guy doesn't know he keeps being summoned

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

This manga was a short run. The MC is just a regular working guy who keeps being summoned to another world, helps someone, then gets sent back before he even notices he was taken to another world.

The first summon I remember, the MC was feeding his cat a snack, then he gets summoned where a big sabertooth cat was blocking some kids from escaping. The MC's snack distracted the big cat long enough for the kids to escape. Then the MC gets sent home before he notices anything.

Another one, the MC was getting a drink from a vending machine, accidentally gets soup, then get summoned to some guy that's lost in the desert. MC give the man his soup, then gets sent back.

This is how the manga goes, with different situations. It's later revealed that his cat may have something to do with his constant summoning.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this one has come up before, but I've had no luck so far locating it.

Comment: I think I remember a scene involving ice cream as well.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I'm guessing https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/236005, which has been asked/answered a bunch of times. There's also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/228363 for a different "multi-summon" manga. No idea if the details match either.

Comment: @qazmlpok: I don't think so. A key aspect of this is that the guy being transported is, at least initially, unaware that he's being summoned. I've read this one before... I'm just trying to find where.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: yeah that's the one. Been trying to fine it for awhile. Thank you

Comment: @SomeGuy: Thanks for the accept. Yeah, I read through it when I answered before, and it was quite enjoyable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hah! I know this one because I've answered it before at [Manga about a man who is repeatedly transported to a fantasy setting, where he helps the people he meets](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242169/manga-about-a-man-who-is-repeatedly-transported-to-a-fantasy-setting-where-he-h/).

*Part Time Overworlder* by Amaou

[image: Front cover of Part Time Overworlder]

> Meet Tanaka. He’s a 26-year-old freeter - a guy who makes his living on various part-time jobs. He works in warehouses, directs traffic, and generally does whatever work he can find in order to get paid.
>
> However, recently Tanaka has had a problem. He occasionally is transported into another world, usually in front of people who need help. Knowing nothing, can Tanaka add another part-time job to his repertoire?

The first time, he thinks it's just a dream, distracting the monster with some grass, bobbing it like a cat toy.

[image: Saber-toothed tiger attack] [image: Distracting the cat, commenting that it must be a dream] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

It's an exhausted sorcerer (out of MP) leaning against a rock in the forest that he feeds the soup that he accidentally got from the vending machine instead of the beverage he was intended.

[image: Feeding the soup to an exhausted sorcerer] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

It's then a cave lizard that he accidentally feeds work snacks to.

[image: The big-eared cave lizard eating his manju] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

Later, we meet his cat, and he meets the cat monster again, accidentally distracting it with the snack he was trying to feed his cat.

[image: Accidentally feeding the cat monster] <sub>Click to enlarge</sub>

And indeed, the last translated chapter I've found (chapter 18), it's implied that his cat, Eyebrows, is a "light god" who ran away to get a break from prayers, with the "dark god" (an identical cat but with dark fur) having also shown up.

Found by remembering that I might have answered this before, and searching for `user:23243 [manga] jobs`, which looks for questions that I've asked or answered in the [manga](/questions/tagged/manga) category and which have the word "jobs" in them. :-D

Comment: Lol that way of finding it! Congrats! ... Uh, does that mean this question should be labelled as a dupe?

Comment: @Malady: No, because the other one was never accepted, so we don't know for certain that it was the right answer.